# Podio tags API call

Tags: json, api, podio, make.com

I want to add tags to Podio item over Podio API, but I am struggling to format the json body correctly.

As I am receiving 400, I guess my request is correct and the problem is in the json format. See the code below.

Any suggestions, please?

Just to make sure, I use Integromat to make the API call (Podio`s "Make an API call" module)

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": 400,
        "headers": {
            "date": "Tue, 16 Mar 2021 12:10:31 GMT",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "content-length": "291",
            "connection": "close",
            "server": "nginx",
            "x-rate-limit-remaining": "9990",
            "x-rate-limit-limit": "10000",
            "x-podio-auth-ref": "********",
            "x-podio-request-id": "********"
        },
        "body": {
            "error_parameters": {},
            "error_detail": null,
            "error_propagate": false,
            "request": {
                "url": "http://api.podio.com/tag/item/***********/",
                "query_string": "",
                "method": "POST"
            },
            "error_description": "Invalid value {\"{text}\": [\"test1\", \"test2\"]} (object): must be array",
            "error": "invalid_value"
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "url": "https://api.podio.com/tag/item/***********/",/",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "***",
            "User-Agent": "Integromat/production"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "body": {
            "{text}": [
                "test1",
                "test2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your Error message.

Comment: It is actually in the code snippet: "Invalid value {\"{text}\": [\"test1\", \"test2\"]} (object): must be array"

Answer (score 0):

Your body is wrong.

If you want to create tags with values "test1" and "test2", your body should be:

```
["foo","bar"]
```

It should be a JSON array of tags.